# msysgit won't recognize a .git folder

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I'm installing a Windows server (2012) with Git (msysgit). The SSH connection between server and client works perfect but I can't clone a git folder to the client.

On the server is a clean --bare git folder ready, initialized with `git init`

I've updated the path variable to recognize the git  executables using CMD and the path setting in system variables:

```
Set PATH=%PATH%;” C:\Program files\Git\bin; C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd”
```

I'm trying to connect by using Git Extensions on the client with the ssh url:

```
ssh:\\administrator@192.168.44.128\Documents\DemoProject
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. Can anyone help me? Do I need to grand a service or user acces to some files or directories?

[image]

Comment: There is actually a git repo on \Documents\DemoProject on that server? If you connect to that host through ssh, what is the cd command you have to run in order to reach that directory? Or what is the output of pwd when going into that directory through ssh?

Comment: It is an existing folder as shown in the putty screen. The SSH client opens by default in the home directory of the user, set bij OpenSSH to C:\users\<username>. So I've to use cd /Documents/DemoProject to get to the correct folder, which I do via Git but won't recognize it.

Comment: did you try with C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/DemoProject or something along those lines?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I've tried to connect via ssh with all  possible path possibilities. <username>@<ip>/C:\folder\folder\folder\........\.git all the way until I've only used the .git folder after the ip adress. And still it won't recognize the .git folder.